# Handwriting cardinal numbers

Tags: notation, set-theory, convention

In books the cardinal numbers are usually written with a gothic font.

Is there any convention how to handwrite cardinal numbers, in particular, how to handwrite the continuum ($\mathfrak c$)

Comment: Some lecturers use Sütterlin https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%BCtterlin

Comment: Do you mean $\aleph$ and $\beth$???

Comment: I mean the continuum before all. Besides, see the gothic notation in this script, page 52: http://www.mimuw.edu.pl/~urzy/Pmat/pomat.pdf

Comment: Just practice your Gothic font. If nothing else, mathematics had taught me how to write in various fonts by hand.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: Can you please suggest a source how to learn the Gothic font?

Comment: Well, just use $\LaTeX$ to generate a line of each letter, then print it out, then put a blank paper on top, and just trace it until you get the hang of it.